# Change height of dynamically created textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

```
$("#btnwrite").click(function(){
        $(".sent").after("<textarea class='write'></textarea>");
});
```

This creates a textarea after each `sent` paragraph.
Now, I want to resize height of textarea when user types in it:

```
function h(e) {
    $(e).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(e.scrollHeight);
}
$('textarea').each(function () {
  h(this);
}).on('input', function () {
  h(this);
});
```

This works perfectly if textarea is inside starting DOM, but doesn't work for dinamically created textareas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to use a delegated event handler

```
function h() {
    $(this).css({'height':'auto','overflow-y':'hidden'}).height(this.scrollHeight);
}

$(document).on('input', 'textarea', h).trigger('input');
```